# How to get div to go under another div

Tags: css, html, web

I am making a website. when i scroll up the page some of the divs do not go behind the menu at the top of the page how do I make it so they go underneath. The webpage is [gaigo.zapto.org](http://gaigo.zapto.org). If you look at the page and try to scroll you will see what I mean. Thanks for any help in advance.

**Edit:**
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong in this question to receive negative points?

Comment: Dont linkto a website, Place relevant code here, and/or make a working demo on jsfiddle.net. Welcome on SO

Comment: Take a look at the z-index css property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: Why are people so quick to moan and not help out? I dont know what is causing it so I don't know what code to post. The website was purely there so that you can see what I mean not for you to go diving into the code but you can if you want to.

Comment: you need to add z index in your fixed header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merely set the z-index of `#MainBar` to a larger value:

```
#MainBar {
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the general context, you should use `z-index` to specify the "z height", or the order of overlapping of elements.

In this case, you would want to set the `z-index` of your menu bar to a value higher than any other `z-index` value of any element in the page. I would suspect `1` to be enough.

```
#MainBar {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

You might want to apply this to other fixed elements (such as the nav bar) as well.

A note about `z-index`: this attribute only affects elements which have a specified `position` attribute. In this case your header is `fixed` so it should work, but be careful of this.